# Scrapy parse_node() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm facing some issues with the `parse_node` method in Scrapy:

```
class s1(scrapy.spiders.XMLFeedSpider):
name = "s1"
handle_httpstatus_list = [400,401,403,404,408,410,500,502,503,504]
allowed_domains = ["xxx"]
start_urls = ["xxx"]
main_url = start_urls[0]
jobs_list = []
tracker = SummaryTracker()
itertag = "miojob"
counter = 0


def parse_node(self, response, node):
    if response.status in [400,401,403,404,408,410,500,502,503,504]:
        time.sleep(60)
        yield scrapy.Request(self.main_url, callback=self.parse_node, errback=self.err1, dont_filter = True)
    else:
    #Some Code #
        yield scrapy.Request(self.main_url, callback=self.parse_node, errback=self.err1, dont_filter = True)
```

This is part of a scrapy-bot that recursively scrape the same page to extract the last ten items. Everything works except for the last `scrapy.Request`, because it gives me this error:
*"parse_node() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)"*
Instead if I use a simple `Request(self.main_url)` it works, but I can't use the errback because it needs a callback. I tried to pass additional arguments to `parse_node` like this:

```
yield scrapy.Request(self.main_url, callback=self.parse_node(arg1,arg2), errback=self.err1, dont_filter = True)
```

but it gives me an Assertion error, probably because the arguments are wrong?

Have you any idea on how to solve this? Passing the correct args to `parse_node`, in the way I can use also the errback callable.

Comment: a callback method should only contain 2 arguments, `self` and `response`, so remove `node`

Comment: @eLRuLL If i remove node from parse_node will raise an error similar to the old one!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
def parse_node(self, response):
<yourcode>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by reading the source code here:
https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/feed.py

The old Request now is:

```
yield scrapy.Request(self.main_url, callback=self.parse,errback=self.err1, dont_filter = True)
```

The tweak here is calling the parse method, instead of the parse_node because "parse" will pass the Selector(node) to parse_node.